# What if there is no thread for call back of asynchronous function

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I head that when we make a asynchronous request then a thread from the threadpool will be assign to that request and when that request goes to the database as a sql query, until the query finished the thead allocated for that request will be freed and then another request can use that thread.

So my problem is lets think a situation where all the threads have been allocated for request and there is no thread in threadpool. Then imagine a call back of a sql query triggered and how CPU handle this callback since there is no free thread in threadpool.

Comment: _[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)_

Comment: If the limit returned by [`ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_ThreadPool_GetMaxThreads_System_Int32__System_Int32__) would be exceeded, then the code will BLOCK until another thread becomes available, which is A Bad Thing. However, in many cases there will be no need for it to create a thread (as per the article linked by MickyD).

Comment: The .NET has separate thread pool for I/O callback operations (which sometime is called I/O thread pool), so the exhaustion of a worker thread pool, which serves the input requests, may have only indirect influence on the I/O thread pool in meaning that more input requests will cause more I/O callbacks. So what will happen with an I/O callback in case of worker thread pool exhaustion depends mostly on whether a synchronization context which dispatches the execution to a worker thread is used or not (it will be waiting for a thread in former case or will be immediately executed in latter).

Answer (score -1):

Normally, the processor manages the Threads' stacks, but if you start throwing threads without any control at the programming level, it can block the developer and in fact the application, The maximum number of threads is determined by the amount of physical resources available.

ThreadPool.GetAvailalbeThreads returns the number of threads that are available currently in a pool. It is the number of maximum threads minus currently active threads.

```
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workers, out ports);
```